# QT C++ connect crashes program

Tags: c++, qt

I learn how slots/signals work.
I have a simple UDP sniffer implementation class, where I set the IP of the network card from the outside using the setIp method.

```
#include "udpsocket.h"
#include "visualisesniffer.h"

udpSocket::udpSocket()
{
    QUdpSocket *socket = new QUdpSocket;
    socket -> bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 443);
    connect(this, &udpSocket::ipChanged, this, &udpSocket::reBind);
    connect(socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &udpSocket::readData);
}

void udpSocket::setIp(QString ipAddr){
    ip = ipAddr;
    emit ipChanged();
}

void udpSocket::reBind(){
    socket -> bind(static_cast<QHostAddress>(ip), 443);
}

void udpSocket::readData(){
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;

    while(socket->hasPendingDatagrams()){
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket -> readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &sender, &senderPort);
        qDebug() << datagram.data() << "IP  " + sender.toString() << "Port " + QString("%1").arg(senderPort);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QObject>
class udpSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void readData();
    void reBind();
signals:
    void ipChanged();
public:
    udpSocket();
    void setIp(QString ipAddr);
private:
    QUdpSocket* socket;
    QString ip;
};
```

Next, I want the connect (this, &udpSocket::ipChanged, this, &udpSocket::reBind) signal to respond to a change in ip, and then the socket will rebind its IP using it and continue its work with another IP. To do this, I launch the program, select an IP through a separately written menu, then initialize the above-described class and after calling setIp the program crashes, if I do not use the setIp method everything works fine. I would be grateful for your help in fixing this problem.
Qt5, MinGW C++, qmake

Comment: Typo: change `QUdpSocket *socket = new QUdpSocket` to `socket = new QUdpSocket`

Comment: Whups. Accidentally made a new `socket` variable that [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `udpSocket::socket`.

Comment: By the way, I don't see the point of making ``socket`` a pointer. Why not just have the ``QUdpSocket`` as a member?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you are defining a new variable with the same name, **socket**, and it is being pointed at the new QUdpSocket rather than the member variable. The problem is in the following line of your constructor

```
QUdpSocket *socket = new QUdpSocket;
```

Here you are declaring a new variable with the same name **socket** and your member variable is not getting instantiated.

Change the line to the following

```
 socket = new QUdpSocket;
```

Your member variable **socket** will be pointed at a valid **QUdpSocket** instance and should not crash anymore. I hope it helps.

Comment: I am short of word and not sure how to put it in a sentence. Any suggestions?

Comment: *Here you are defining a new variable with the same name, `socket`, and it is being pointed at the new `QUdpSocket` rather than the member variable.* Looks about right.